# How to pass multiple jquery datepicker parameters from view to controller in MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has to pass a start date, an end date, and a guestnumbers int to a controller.

The view is this with formatting stripped out ....

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BookingCalculation", new { BookingFrom = "BookingFrom", BookingTo = "BookingTo", GuestNumbers = "GuestNumbers" },FormMethod.Post)) 
    {
           @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("BookingFrom").DefaultDate(DateTime.Today).MinDate(DateTime.Today)
   @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("BookingTo").DefaultDate(DateTime.Today).NumberOfMonths(2) 
   @Html.TextArea("GuestNumbers","2") 
    <input type ="submit" value ="submit" />
        }
```

The Controller is this ....

```
 public ActionResult Index(string BookingFrom, string BookingTo, int? GuestNumbers) {
```

I passed the datetime through as a string so it can take null values.

How do I wire up the parameters to pass data through? It always passes null no matter what I set. Yet the two are connected as a click on the Index in  (Html.BeginForm("Index" takes me to the method.

It doesn't throw any errors just doesn't pass data across.

As you can tell I am a noob at ASP.net. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create a view model that represents the data you want to edit and let MVC take care of the binding

```
public class BookingVM
{
  public DateTime? BookingFrom { get; set; }
  public DateTime? BookingTo { get; set; }

  [Display(Name="Please enter number of guests")]
  [Range(1, 10)] // optional validation
  public int? GuestNumbers { get; set; } // not sure why you would want this to be nullable?
}
```

BookingCalculationController

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  BookingVM model = new BookingVM();
  // You can set default properties here (e.g. model.GuestNumbers = 2;)
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(BookingVM model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // return the view to correct validation errors
    return View(model);
  }
  // its valid so save values and redirect somewhere
  return RedirectToAction("...");
}
```

View

```
@model BookingVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker(m => m.BookingFrom)
  @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker(m => m.BookingFrom)

  @LabelFor(m => m.GuestNumbers)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GuestNumbers)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GuestNumbers)

  <input type ="submit" value ="submit" />
}
```

Don't forget to include the jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive files if you want client side validation

Comment: Thanks so much for such a comprehensive answer! There is far more to this than I realised :-)